# What is the fastest way to reach enlightenment?

Tags: the-buddha, meditation, nirvana

I am asking for reference request and sutras where a person can cut through samsara quickly and obtain liberation.

I have heard a story when Buddha was asked this question and he replied "Sound". However I haven't found any reference of this & don't know how much accurate this is.

Thoughts are more than welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably thinking of the [Bahiya Sutta (Udana 1.10)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.10.than.html).

Once there was a bark-clad ascetic Bahiya who thought he was enlightened, but a deva told him that he wasn't and asked him to seek out the Buddha for his guidance.

He found the Buddha who gave him a brief instruction, which resulted in his near-immediate enlightenment. Very shortly after that, he was killed in a freak accident. The Buddha said that Bahiya became totally unbound (i.e. enlightened).

What did the Buddha teach him? (translated by Thanissaro)

> "Then, Bāhiya, you should train yourself thus: In reference to the
>   seen, there will be only the seen. In reference to the heard, only the
>   heard. In reference to the sensed, only the sensed. In reference to
>   the cognized, only the cognized. That is how you should train
>   yourself. When for you there will be only the seen in reference to the
>   seen, only the heard in reference to the heard, only the sensed in
>   reference to the sensed, only the cognized in reference to the
>   cognized, then, Bāhiya, there is no you in connection with that. When
>   there is no you in connection with that, there is no you there. When
>   there is no you there, you are neither here nor yonder nor between the
>   two. This, just this, is the end of stress."

Alternative translation from [here](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.1.10.irel.html) (Ireland):

> "Herein, Bahiya, you should train yourself thus: 'In the seen will be
>   merely what is seen; in the heard will be merely what is heard; in the
>   sensed will be merely what is sensed; in the cognized will be merely
>   what is cognized.' In this way you should train yourself, Bahiya.
>
> "When, Bahiya, for you in the seen is merely what is seen... in the
>   cognized is merely what is cognized, then, Bahiya, you will not be
>   'with that.' When, Bahiya, you are not 'with that,' then, Bahiya, you
>   will not be 'in that.' When, Bahiya, you are not 'in that,' then,
>   Bahiya, you will be neither here nor beyond nor in between the two.
>   Just this is the end of suffering."

This is a teaching on [anatta](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/25302/471).

However, this may not work for everyone as it did on Bahiya, because Bahiya apparently was already advanced in attainment. Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/22547/471).

For complete beginners, study of the [Dhamma](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/index.html) (in order to cultivate [Right View](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sacca/sacca4/samma-ditthi/index.html)) and practice of the [five precepts](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ati/ptf/dhamma/sila/pancasila.html) and [virtue (sila)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/ptf/dhamma/sila/index.html) is recommended. Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/26240/471).

Comment: Thanks Ruben,if you know more stories about this please feel free to add to your answer,soon I will accept it

Comment: Although I upvoted this answer, I disagree with your interpretation of this quote as a teaching about anatta. To me this clearly looks like a teaching on *tathata*, transcending the semiotic process of perception with its tendency for reinforcing the reifications it relies on.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not tagged your question as `theravada`-only, I assume you accept answers from all traditions.

In Mahayana, we have a notion of different paths suitable for people of different predilections. The Tibetan tradition has developed two methods, somewhat similar to each other, that are said to allow a serious practitioner to achieve Enlightenment in one lifetime, or even faster.

These methods are known as Mahamudra and Dzogchen. In my understanding, both work by approximating the target state of Nirvana or suchness that Buddha's teaching culminates in. Here I will boil them down to their essential point, hoping to make them available to Internet-age students. If my presentation looks misleading or incomplete, feel free to study traditional literature or practice under the guidance of a qualified teacher.

Basically, the fastest way to Enlightenment consists in "leaving everything as is" and attaining an unwavering conviction and confidence that the regular unmodified state of things is already the "Great Perfection".

Of course, this method assumes one does not have coarse mental and emotional obscurations. In other words, this method assumes that the student is already pretty close to Enlightenment.

There is also a huge difference between taking this "view" as an operative basis of one's emotional mind versus simply thinking that "everything is perfect" when it's not -- on one hand, or simply giving up and staying a fool -- on the other.

When taken correctly, this view results in an effortless state of no attachment, no craving, no aversion, no side-taking, complete non-judgmental acceptance of "oneself" and "the world", dissolution of subject/object duality, perfect realization of metta, karuna, mudita and upekkha, cessation of all suffering, feeling of liberation or spontaneity, and absolute unconditional love.

Comment: this is a really interesting answer,would you mind adding some information on dzongchen

Comment: You can Google it!

Comment: I can't attest that Andrei's description of Mahamudra and Dzogchen is correct, because I really don't know either of them, but his description doesn't seem obviously at odds with what I've heard other people I respect say. Plus, Andrei is an actual practitioner of these IIRC.

Comment: I've been thinking to read a bit more about Mahamudra although some teachers advise against reading about Tantra until one has had the initiation... I remember that book you recommended me with Mahamudra in the title, but I also saw this: https://www.wisdompubs.org/book/mahamudra-0

Comment: Have you heard of that one or would recommend it?

Comment: I agree that Varjrayana should be practiced under the guidance of a qualified teacher. Not because you'll anger the spirits or something, but just because it would be as useful as for a child to open the medicine box and start eating the pills at random. Plus, the most potent teachings have childproof lids anyway. Lama Yeshe was a good guy and the text he teaches in that book is an authentic traditional teaching - but I would still recommend to try and establish an actual *personal* relationship with a qualified Vajra Master instead of trying to self-medicate.

Comment: The thing is that Dzogchen is neither Sutta nor Tantra and technically may be practised along with both (including prelims). Practically, it depends on Nyingmapa that teaches you. Dzogchen in this way is more relaxed since Bodhicitta and the rest automatically arises from realising Rigpa.

Comment: @YesheTenley if you want to know more about what Dzogchen is, read "The Crystal and the Way of Light: Sutra, Tantra and Dzogchen", if you want I can send you that book by post.

Comment: @bodhihammer me too, me too :)

Comment: @AndreiVolkov Fine, how do I do this ? Twitter pm (ChrisW once suggested, I am stealing it) ?

Comment: @bodhihammer  - My email address is in my profile.

Answer (score -1):

Correct way to enlightenment is *arya ashtangika marga* i.e. the "Noble Eightfold Path".